# Fetch external API currency rates, then save the results to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

The task I'm doing is, fetch external API, then save the results to database.

I'm a beginner, I really wanna improve my code, to handle error well, and remove redundant code. The code is working, but I'm bit confused with promise and try-catch. I watched some tutorial, still not sure in the situation which way is better. Anyone could please help me? I really appreciate it!

```
//app.js
const express = require('express')
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args))
const app = express()
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
const ExternalAPI = 'https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest'

const db = new sqlite3.Database('currency.db');

const connectDatabase = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(new Error(`Failed to connect to database: ${err.message}`));
        });
        db.on('open', () => {
            console.log('Connected to the currency database.');
            resolve(db);
        });
    });
};

const createTable = (db) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.run(
            `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS results (
          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          request_at TEXT NOT NULL,
          rate_USD REAL NOT NULL,
          rate_EUR REAL NOT NULL,
          rate_GBP REAL NOT NULL,
          rate_CNY REAL NOT NULL
        )`,
            (err) => {
                if (err) reject(new Error(`Failed to create table: ${err.message}`))
                else resolve();
            }
        );
    });
};

const connectDatabaseAndTable = async () => {
    try {
        await connectDatabase();
        await createTable();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};



const fetchExchangeRates = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(ExternalAPI)
        const data = await res.json()
        return data
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch exchange rates')
    }
}

const insertExchangeRatesAndTimeIntoDB = async (db, rates) => {
    const requestAt = new Date().toLocaleString()
    const { USD, EUR, GBP, CNY } = rates
    const query = `INSERT INTO results(request_at, rate_USD, rate_EUR, rate_GBP, rate_CNY) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)`
    const params = [requestAt, USD, EUR, GBP, CNY]
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.run(query, params, (err) => {
                if (err) reject(err)
                else resolve()
            })
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        throw new Error('Failed to insert exchange rates into the database')
    }
}

const retrieveExchangeRatesFromDB = async (db) => {
    try {
        db.all(`SELECT * FROM results`, [], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) console.error(err.message);
            rows.map((row) => console.log(row))
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        throw new Error('Failed to retrieve exchange rates from the database')
    }
}

 const closeDB = (db) => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         db.close((err) => {
             if (err) {
                 console.error(err)
                 reject(err);
             } else resolve()
         })
     })
 }

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        connectDatabaseAndTable()
        const exchangeRates = await fetchExchangeRates()
        await insertExchangeRatesAndTimeIntoDB(db, exchangeRates.rates)
        const retrievedRates = await retrieveExchangeRatesFromDB(db)
        console.log(retrievedRates)
        closeDB(db)
        res.json({ status: 200, success: true })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        res.status(500).send('Something went wrong...')
    }
})

module.exports = app
```

```
//index.js
const express = require('express')
const app = require('./app')
const PORT = 5005

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: You are using promises conservatively. Example 1: await connectDatabase();
 await createTable(); Example 2: await fetch(ExternalAPI)
 await res.json(); In both cases you resolve promise A and _then_ resolve promise B. There's an opportunity to chain them. Here the difference will be trivial, but it's a good habit to get into. For large tasks we can schedule A on one core, B on another core, and there's some overlap, which reduces elapsed wallclock time. Also, `.get()` opens / closes DB, but remembering that "it's still open" would reduce   latency for repeated GETs. Please COMMIT inserts.